# regex match but not include in group

Tags: c#, regex

I'm doing a little regex to recognize a complex number. I need it in a C# school program.
I must recognize complex numbers like:
3+5i
3+5k
4-i5
6+f7

So, the imaginary part can have any char behind or ahead the value.
I wrote this Regex:

```
(?<reale>[+-]?\d+)(?<immaginaria>[+-]\d+[a-zA-Z]|[+-][a-zA-Z]\d+)
```

The problem is, when I take the group called "immaginaria" I have got it with the imaginary part char (like i or j) and I'd like to get it without..
I found the solution of using Look-ahead and Look-behind but but I have got a problem while trying to implement it in my regex (It's the first regex I write)

```
(?<reale>[+-]?\d+)(?<immaginaria>[+-]\d+(?=[a-zA-Z])|[+-](?=[a-zA-Z])\d+)
```

Comment: The easy way buddy is to replace that char in immaginaria result `[a-zA-Z]` with an empty char ` `

Comment: Yes, It was the easy way and I did it but I didn't like to perform an extra operation in my code :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your first attempt a little bit to separate the sign and the value of the imaginary part, you can concatenate them later after a successful match:

```
(?<reale>[+-]?\d+)((?<immaginariasign>[+-])(?<immaginaria>\d+)[a-zA-Z]|(?<immaginariasign>[+-])[a-zA-Z](?<immaginaria>\d+))
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. What should I do if I'd like to match string like 3 (putting 3 in real group and leaving empty the imaginary group), 3j (putting 3 in imaginary group leaving empty the real group)? . So I'd like to match if there is only the imaginary part or only the real part. (I will check in c# code what exists or not). Did I make myself clear?

Comment: @RandomOverflow add an `?` to the regex. It makes the group optional.